excecuting sql file gets hung and stalls
I have a 5GB sql file which I'm trying to excecute using Navicat.  I tried 3 times and each time the software got hung.  I then divided the sql file into 1/50th of its size so that it is only 111 MB but even that is too large. By the way, the file is a wiktionary dump.
Can I execute this file with command line or should I not even bother?  Also, I've never used mysql before, so don't assume I will know what you're talking about.

Keep dividing. Eventually it will finish, or you'll find the actual problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Well, I can't divide the thing into 50 parts because then I would have to manually load each one unless I'm mistaken and there is a way for my Navicat to loop over a set of file and execute them.
